# How to install ESlint with no npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am working on enterprise computer with no internet access nor node (npm).
I have downloaded ESlint manually and installed it to VS Code. Now it says that i need to use npm command for it to work, my question is how can i run ESlint globally without npm command/Node? Is it possible?

This what i get:

To use ESLint please install eslint by running npm install eslint in the workspace folder Supreme

or globally using 'npm install -g eslint'. You need to reopen the workspace after installing eslint.

after trying to set it right i get:

PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Supreme> eslint --init

eslint : The term 'eslint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try

Comment: From which link you have downloaded the `ESLint` and manually installed it into `VSCode`?

Comment: the vs code market

Comment: @yaniz You mean [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint) extension?

Comment: @DavidR Yes but i doownloed vsix from [link]https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint[/link]

Answer (score 1):

`npm` is mostly just moving files around for you - if you want to install it without `npm`, just move the files around yourself.

E.g. go grab the [latest release of eslint from github](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/releases), copy it to your enterprise computer (network/flash drive?) and unpack it. Then call it directly using `node path/to/bin/eslint.js`.

If you have node.js installed it should work - if not, you'll need to use a similar approach to install that.

To execute it without prefixing the command with `node`, e.g. just `eslint`, you would need to install a `.cmd` wrapper alongside it. `npm` does this using [cmd-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmd-shim)

If you wanted to run it without having node.js installed, then you would need to package the node.js runtime and eslint together - options for this include [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) and [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe)

To get VSCode to run eslint, you would need to setup a custom task runner by adding a `tasks.js` file to your project - e.g:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "eslint-fix",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "path/to/your/packaged/eslint --fix"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can use the `Tasks: Run Task` command to find and execute it - or setup a shortcut - for more details see the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

Comment: I kind of lost in your answer, i don't have nodejs installed and don't have internet access, i can (and have) download  latest release of eslint from GitHub from remote computer and send it via email to the work PC. now where i unpack this zip, and what command should i run from vs code?

Comment: if you don't have node.js installed, and can't install it by copying it to the machine - then you'll have to package eslint into an executable using pkg or nexe (links in my answer) - then copy that executable to the machine and setup a VSCode task that runs it for you (https://vscode.rocks/tasks/)

Comment: A guide how to achieve a standalone binary for a target platform and given node major version using pkg is available here: 
https://dev.to/jochemstoel/bundle-your-node-app-to-a-single-executable-for-windows-linux-and-osx-2c89

I managed to create a Windows executable bundling node 10, please note that the sample says require('.') in main.js - I had to change this to a relative path like require('./main.js') pkg also supports executables for Mac and Linux OS and will default build all three.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Github repo for creating a tailored Eslint standalone binary here:
[Eslint-Standalone](https://github.com/toreaurstadboss/eslint-standalone/blob/master/Readme.md)

This uses node, npm and pkg to build a eslint tool into a binary, such as an exe for win platform. You can then use that exe and copy it into your network at work with restrictions when it comes to npm.

Answer (score 1):

I found out my distro, Ubuntu 20.04, offers `eslint` through apt (although outdated, because only supports up to ES2018), so I don't need to install it through npm. Creating `.eslintrc.json` required me to have a `package.json`, however once I create the `.eslintrc.*` file, I can get rid of `package.json`.

Then I can run `eslint ~/some_code.js` anywhere as long as an eslintrc file is present. You can specify any eslintrc file to use by using `-c`, ex. `eslint -c ~/.eslintrc.json some_code.js`.

Sample `.eslintrc.json` for running code in browser, using spaces, unix linebreaks, double quotes for strings, and always semicolons:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```